# removing commented out code from webpage

Tags: html, comments, ssi

I am cleaning up a .cfm file and removing commented out code. I'm not sure what can be safely removed, because doesn't so scripting languages use commented out code like SSI?

For example

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @import "../styles/ie.css";
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I think is important but do I need to keep anything between `<!--` and `-->` in this:

```
<!-- /#toolbar -->

    <div id="content">

    <div id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar">
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div id="sidebar-left-inner">
            <p id="date"></p>
            <cfinclude template="requires/nowProcessing.cfm">
            <!-- /.now-serving -->

            <div id="sub-nav">
            <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="leftMenuInclude" -->
```

Not sure if relevant but the file contains JavaScript and CSS and possibly other languages.

EDIT:Out of curiousity what language are these from?

```
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="leftMenuInclude" -->
<!-- /#main -->
<!-- /#content -->
```

Comment: are you writing a script to remove commented out code or manually removing?

Comment: Why do you what to remove the commented out markup? This is cold fusion template language (I googled it).

Comment: Why? Fore readability purposes. What do you mean "This is cold fusion template" I know that's what .cfm stands for. Are you saying I can't delete any comments?

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think you should be removing comments for "readability purposes" if you cannot event tell which comments have a functionality. Mind you most of the time comments are actually put in place for the exact reason that you want to remove them.

Comment: @ArnarYngvason do you prescribe to commenting out code and not removing it? Others told me this is a bad practice, and in school I loosed marks for this.

Comment: I don't think there is an absolute answer to this question. Commenting out code (or even markup) rather than deleting can in some cases be useful as it provides perspective on how the code evolved or if you're not sure if you think you might want to undo your changes or even use the code somewhere else later. Removing commented out code really comes down to your own personal judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't using a script this is easy... Simply remove commented out code only!

This does not mean that you should remove everything between:

```
<!-- -->
```

Some will be comments, for example:

```
<!-- this is a comment to explain something -->
```

And some will be conditional comments, for example:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]> <![endif]-->
```

Use your knowledge of the code to remove the appropriate commented out code... aka, code that has no purpose!

Make sure you understand the difference between comments and commented out code!

Answer (score 0):

That is a conditional comment.  It will target less than IE8 because of this line. So its there for a purpose.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx